# git keep local file, do not let merge with origin delete it

Tags: git

I have a local branch where I need a file to start my server, let's call it config.conf. Every time I merge the latest code from origin, origin does not have it, so it gets deleted/removed on my local branch. how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Umm, Is `config.conf` untracked?. Can you show what `git status` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project folder should have .gitignore file in it. If you cant find it, create one. It is a hidden file, but you can have access to it using text editor, like Sublime Text.

Add the path of the file you want to ignore and commit .gitignore changes
It will look something like this

```
config.conf
```

That should help